# Comparing the Finite Square Well and Infinite Square Well Energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This form of diagram keeps appearing when comparing a particle in a box solution to a finite square well.
[image]

Obviously for a infinite square well:

$$E_n = n^2 \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2mL^2}$$

So I am assuming they are plotting normalized energy (ie: $E_n/  (\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2mL^2})$). For the finite well, we have to solve a transcendental equations  (one for even and the other for odd) which have the following form:

$$\mu^2 + \xi^2 = z_0^2$$
$$\xi = \mu \tan(\mu)$$

Where $z_0 = a \frac{\sqrt{2mV_0}}{\hbar}$$\xi = \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}a$. Hence for intersection points, I can take the $\xi$ value and find the normalized value by:

$$E = \frac{\xi^2}{\pi^2} \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2mL^2}$$

Similarily, the even solutions take on the form:

$$\mu^2 + \xi^2 = z_0^2$$
$$\xi = -\mu \cot(\mu)$$

However, whenever I plot these functions and find the intersection point (say $z_0 = 10$ which provides at least the 4 lowest possible energies), I never get anything qualitatively near this diagram. The lowest $\xi$ value I get is 2.514 which leads to a value of 0.64 in normalized energy units. 4th energy level (when you account for both even and odd solutions) is around 8, not 11. something as the diagram suggests. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly, but the diagram at the start has 3 not 4 bound states in the finite well.